# Excel paste data according to row

Tags: excel, paste

I have 2 excel file which i need to combine the data together.

I had simplified as follow with some sample data.

Excel File 1

> Column 1 with Item Code, lets say 1, 2, 3
>
> Column 2 with Item Cost, lets say $1, $2, $3

Excel File 2

> Column 1 with Item Code, Lets say 1, 3, and 4

I want to copy all the Column 2 of Excel file 1, paste into Excel file 2, which paste matching to Column one of Excel file 2. It will skip the data if the column one not match.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Excel functions (sadly, it works only when both workbooks are open). Let us presume that "data source" workbook is located at "C:\Users\User\source.xls", and has it's data in worksheet named "Sheet1", in columns A and B respectively. Let's also presume, that your target workbook's "key" data is in column A. Then you should populate needed column using following functions, starting with row 1: `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'C:\Users\User\[source.xls]Sheet1'!",ADDRESS(MATCH($A1,'C:\Users\User\[source.xls]Sheet1'!A:A),2,1,1,1)),1)`.
2. Using following VBA macros from "destination" workbook, while populated sheet is active:

   ```
   Sub Main()
       Dim a As Application, b As workbook, s As Worksheet, i As Integer, iMax As Integer, v As Variant
       Set a = GetInvisibleApplication
       Set b = GetWorkbook(a, "C:\Users\Zerth\1.xls")
       Set s = b.Worksheets(1)
       iMax = GetLastRow(ActiveSheet)
       For i = 1 To iMax Step 1
           v = GetValue(s, Cells(i, 1).Value)
           If Not IsNull(v) Then
               Cells(i, 2).Value = v
           End If
       Next i
       a.Quit
   End Sub
   Function GetInvisibleApplication() As Application
       Set GetInvisibleApplication = New Application
       GetInvisibleApplication.Visible = False
       GetInvisibleApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
   End Function
   Function GetWorkbook(ByRef Application As Application, ByVal Path As String) As workbook
       Application.Workbooks.Open Path
       Set GetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks(Application.Workbooks.Count)
   End Function
   Function GetLastRow(ByRef Sheet As Worksheet)
       GetLastRow = Sheet.Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
   End Function
   Function GetValue(ByRef Sheet As Worksheet, ByVal Key As Variant)
       Dim i, iMax As Integer, Result As Variant
       i = 0
       iMax = GetLastRow(Sheet)
       Result = Null
       Do While IsNull(Result) And (i < iMax)
           i = i + 1
           If Sheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = Key Then
               Result = Sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
           End If
       Loop
       GetValue = Result
   End Function
   ```
3. Using [OLEDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLEDB) with any known programming language, where finding your values would be as easy as making any other SQL query (namely, query you would need is `SELECT F2 FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE F1 = @parameter` with [IMEX](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007) turned off).